# What is the best project setup in this situation?

Tags: spring, java-ee-5, myeclipse

The presentation tier will contain 2 web modules (serving different purposes and based on different technologies), the middle tier will be Spring beans without EJBs and the persistence tier will be JPA on Hibernate. I am wondering what would be the best project setup in this case. The IDE I am planning to use is MyEclipse 8.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Java project for the common stuff that's packaged as a JAR file.

Two web projects, each packaged in their own WAR file, that accept the common JAR file as a 3rd party dependency.

> Do I need an EAR?

You can do that if you're using a Java EE app server like WebLogic, JBOSS, Glassfish, Geronimo, or WebSphere.  An EAR won't be an option if you're using a servlet/JSP engine like Tomcat or Jetty to deploy.

> Or just 3 separate projects?

Three projects will have the advantage of looser coupling.  Your two web apps are coupled at the common JAR and database levels, but from a deployment point of view you can alter the rest for one and not affect the other.

> What can be put into the common JAR?
>   What I can think of is JPA entities,
>   DAOs.

Everything that's shared except for the web tier stuff.

> What if 2 WARs try to access the same
>   data at the same time?

That has to do with isolation, table locking, and the design of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Do I need an EAR? Or just 3 separate projects? 

What can be put into the common JAR? What I can think of is JPA entities, DAOs. What if 2 WARs try to access the same data at the same time?

Comment: @Tong Wang - +1 I would package the whole thing in an EAR if you are running on a platform that supports them.